Combine MultiLanguage StoreView & main Language
Is there an elegant way to define that Admin and the main language (in this case Italian) can use the same values? Example, when I duplicate a product, I have to change 4x times the values in Name, Meta, description etc.


Ok  that is exact what I wanted to do but how? I need to avoid the Italian Store View but how.


If your main language is Italian you can leave the structure as it is and only make the translations to Deutch and English on the specifics stores. The italiano store should take the basic values based on the global scope.
This way you only create the product on Italian and create the translations to the other 2 stores updating the values only 3 times.
In case you don't want to make the translations by hand, you can use some module like the blackbird or use deelp to handle that and modify afterwards.
